# Contact being removed from AddressBook after being Selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook, abrecordref

I'm working on some integration between my application and the iPhone's AddressBook.  Here is the flow of my program.

1. User wants to import a contact
2. App Presents "ABPeoplePickerNavigationController" to the User.
3. User selects the contact they want:
4. Delegate Method is called:

Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    self.selectedContact = person;
    [self showNewContactViewThroughController:peoplePicker withRecord:person];
    NSLog(@"should continue after selecting");
    return NO;
}
```

5: In `- (void)showNewContactViewThroughController:withRecord:` We create the AbNewPersonViewController.

```
`ABNewPersonViewController *newController = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];`

`newController.displayedPerson = person;`

`newController.newPersonViewDelegate = self;`
```

And then push it.

6: User hits "Cancel" to quit the ABNewPersonViewController view.
7: Check the Contacts app, the contact they selected in step 3 is gone.  Poof, gone, deleted, removed.

In an attempt to fix this issue, I save the ABRecordRef (to the instance variable "selectedContact").  Then, in `- (void)newPersonViewController:didCompleteWithNewPerson:` I have:

```
if (person) {
//do stuff with the person
else {
        ///
        /// This means they canceled, so we need to save the old person back
        ///
        if (self.selectedContact) {
            ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
            CFErrorRef error = NULL;
            ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, self.selectedContact, &error);
            if (error != NULL) {
                NSLog(@"Error Adding Record: %@", error);
            }
            ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
            if (error != NULL) {
                NSLog(@"AccountDetailTableViewController.newPersonViewController() The old contact was not saved successfully. %@", error);
            }
            self.selectedContact = nil;
        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't seem to do anything.  The code is executed, but the "Old Contact", self.selectedContact, is not saved to the AddressBook.  So, my contacts are still disappearing.  What am I doing wrong?  It appears as though if you hit Cancel in the ABNewPersonViewController, it "removes" the data it was given from the Address Book?  So the person I give it then dies?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by NOT using the `ABNewPersonViewController`, but rather by using the `ABPersonViewController` after the user selected the person they want to use.  The information is no longer being deleted.